# Angularjs injector:modulerr while using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I am Learning AngularJS and want to develop simple example. I want to create a simple routing.
This is `temp.html` document:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf8">
</head>
<body ng-app="routeApp">
    <a href="#/test">TEST</a>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

This is app.js :

```
var app=angular.module('routeApp' ,[])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/test' , {
        templateUrl : 'test.html'
    });
});
```

and This is help.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>TEST PAGE</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got This error

> Error:[$injector:modulerr]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=routeApp&p1=[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
>   K/<@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:7:76
>   gb/p.$injector<@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:46:64
>   d@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:43:309
>   e@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:44:39
>   invoke@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:44:124
>   d@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:42:271
>   g/<@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:42:418
>   r@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:8:5
>   g@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:42:180
>   gb@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:46:250
>   c@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:22:19
>   Uc@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:22:332
>   we@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:21:1
>   @file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:336:241
>   b@file:///E:/YahyaApps/hello/angular.min.js:38:260

please Help ME!!!!

Comment: You will have to inject the router module when you call: `.module('routeApp', ['ngRoute'])`

Comment: you need to have a dependancy for `angular-route` module: `angular.module('routeApp', ['ngRoute'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `ngRoute` added as a dependency :

```js
var app=angular.module('routeApp',['ngRoute']) //<---
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/test' , {
        templateUrl : 'test.html'
    });
});
```